# Moving from a sql server database to one that doesn't require the client to install a server (C# Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm going to try to keep this as short and to the point as I can.

**The Problem**

I'm trying to use a sqlite database with the entity framework. I am using .NET 4.5, and Visual Studio 2013.

I've installed the appropriate sqlite nuget packages, and I've followed a bunch of tutorials online to accomplish this, but *Visual Studio doesn't care*.

No matter what I do, I can't connect to my sqlite database.

I made an application that includes a database file. I want to be able to distribute it as a standalone application that doesn't require additional installations (sql server, etc.).

**What I've Tried**

Like I said, I've been trying to get sqlite to play nice with Visual Studio all night, but I've had no luck.

I've been looking around for other database types, but I can't seem to find any that don't require additional installs AND can use the entity framework.

I've seen people suggest using a Microsoft Access database file, but I haven't had luck getting that to work with EF either.

**My Questions**

- Does anybody know why Visual Studio doesn't give me the option to connect to a sqlite database?
- Does a Microsoft SQL Server Compact database require an install from the client?

  - If not, how can I use it with my existing code?
- Can I use a Microsoft Access database file with the Entity Framework?
- Is there a better option that I have not pursued yet?

**The End**

Like usual, I am probably over-thinking this whole thing, and there is probably a really simple solution to my problem staring me in the face. Any feedback/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

*Edit:*

As requested, here is my connection string (attempting to get sqlite to work, not the working connection string):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.Linq" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="VVCDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VVCDatabase.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

As far as the code I use to access the database, I use a DbContext to access the database (which works with my current setup).

**Edit Again**

One of the tutorials I have tried to follow is [this one](http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-ii-using-sqlite-with-entity-framework.aspx), and when adding a new connection, they get the option for sqlite:

[image]

I only get the options:

[image]

I've started blank projects, and followed everything exactly, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please add some code where you are connecting to your database please.  And your config file where you have the database path. Sql lite needs to have the correct ef installed for it to work

Comment: @Archlight, I've updated my answer with new information. :)

Comment: Not sure that sqlite supports DataDirectory macro, but what is not working? What have you tried and what errors do you get?

Comment: @ErikEJ, I'm not getting any errors, I'm just getting nothing. I've updated my answer with a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Consider using SQL Server LocalDB. Yes, it's an extra package to install but it doesn't run all the time like SQL Server does.

Comment: See reply 1, sqlite edmx support is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: You need to install the correct vs support package from  the myriad of sqlite packages. And I have only been able to make sqlite Work with EF6 using Code First, not the edm wizard.

2: With SQL Server Compact no client install is required, see my blog for details. With my SQLCE Toolbox installed in VS, you get full ef tooling support.

3: Not as far as I know, no.

4: sqlce or sqlite are your best options, if it must be a free Tool, and EF support is required.

Comment: Thanks for answering all four of my questions. :) I have EF6 installed, and I installed the sqlite packages for EF6, but still no luck. I'm going to give sqlce a try.

Comment: I've given up trying to get sqlite working with EF6, I'm using sqlce now, and it works without any problems. Thanks for the help.