# How can I make\distribute windows form application that doesn't require installation of SQL Server and other dependencies at client side

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installation, setup-project

There are certain dependencies when installing windows form application at client side like .NET Framework, SQL Server (if application uses database) and crystal report engine. I have made application that uses all above. I don't want to install all these things at client side but I only want them to have setup (MSI) and install that at their PC. Is there any way to avoid these dependencies?

PS: I just read about sqlite here in this answer to this partial similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648555/moving-from-a-sql-server-database-to-one-that-doesnt-require-the-client-to-inst).

Comment: What tool are you using to create the setup? Instead of installing a dependency just prompt for a connection string or remove Te dependency from the setup and leave configuration to the user.

Comment: how does the windows application make it's database calls for example is this a remote sql server..? if so then use a config file with the proper datasource username / password...etc... make sure that you are adding a reference to SqlDataClient

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I am adding setup project to solution in visual studio 2010 and adding project output to that project and building that. The main concern is I don't want to leave configuration to user. I want to either remove dependencies completely (if possible) or want to automatically install them along with setup installation (if 1st option isn't possible)

Comment: @MethodMan I am connecting fine with local SQL server (it is not remote, I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on client's PC) . But I really want to not to install this on client's PC nor it is available remotely. Is this really possible? Sorry for being dumb and asking such question but I am really new to all this.

Comment: you do not need to install that on all the pc's you do however need to install certain things like .net framework that's 4.0 or higher, make sure that you are setting the copylocal = true to all the 3rd party .dll's that will be stored in the bin directory.. or create a dependency folder and drop and reference all the assembly  / dll there and make sure that you have a database server setup somewhere that's on a Server..do not install single instances on every machine..that's not the route you want to take. do you have or know of a dba..if so ask them for help

Comment: Hmm I am getting you here but little. I don't have DBA and I've done all database work myself but when coming to installation I lack some knowledge. Well I'll definitely have a look at dependency folder you just pointed too. Thanks for the idea though

Answer (score 0):

I'll be picky and guess that the installation process doesn't actually require  SQL or CR. I could be wrong if you're running code during the install that needs them, but assuming that you're not...

So the SQL issue may just be an app issue. The app runs for the first time and doesn't have a DB to connect to, so show a dialog that is used to connect to a DB. Save the resulting connection string for the app to use later.  You can't possibly know in advance where the users have their DBs so it's the only thing to do.

For CR, there is typically a merge module that you can include in your setup that will install the files you need, which might be a good thing because if your app has references to CR Dlls then it might not load if the Dlls aren't available. The other approach is to find the CR download redistributable and require the user to install it first. There may be a launch condition based on a registry search that you can use to prevent the installation from starting - see Search Target Machine and launch condtions in the setup project.

If your code is NOT directly dependent on CR then again have the app start and find out if CR reports is installed somehow, using whatever method CR says to use. A search for "how to detect that CR is installed" may help.

Comment: I must make it clear here that client has no knowledge of database and application installation. For now I've installed complete SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio on clients system and gave its connection in connection string of App.config so actually there is no connection or SQL issue. I was wondering if it is possible that without installing complete SQL Server I can install my application in client's system which uses DB.
My code is dependent on CR for some reports and you have given a nice option to install that along with my setup(if I am getting you right). I'll search how to do this

Comment: A client that has alreasy installed SQL Server already has, by definition, an understanding of SQL Configurations. The other alternative is for you too include one of the SQL Express type SQLs and use it if this is entirely for the internal use of your app.